# long running process vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have a service ticket management application and users want to open several ticket details on a tab in a MDI frame. Since this application has to communicate through Web XML service with other company, it takes around 15 ~20 seconds. The users most complain is that he needs to wait until a saving process is done. Cursor is working while data is being saved and other can't be done.

What is the most effective way to let user open other window and do something else or save data while data is being saved from other windows?

By the way, this is VB.Net / Windows Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a BackgroundWorker or new thread.  I personally would try using built in asynchronous methods, such as BeginInvoke

http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1443981/Asynchronous-Web-Services-for-Visual-Basic-NET.htm

Keep in mind that asynchronous operations become complicated very quickly, good desighned in very important.

Comment: What is the difference between BackgroundWorker or new thread?

Comment: @Hoorayo: BackgroundWorker executes an operation on a separate thread. Read the reference I have provided ...

Comment: A new thread is a rawer version of a BackgroundWorker.  The worker encapsulates a new thread but provides easy methods to start/stop/cancel the work.  It also raises Events so that it can report progress to your main thread easier.  Like I said in my post though there’s already the BeginInvoke method you can use removing the need for a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) ...

---

Refer to the following:

[Manage a background process by using the BackgroundWorker component](http://en.csharp-online.net/Manage_a_background_process_by_using_the_BackgroundWorker_component)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a web service which is part of a solution which needs to go off and run a method which takes quite a long while to run through. After some experimenting, I decided it was simplest to kick off the long running task in a new thread within the web service and return a custom object to the calling application (which is then used later).

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function StartChecks() As ResponseItem

    Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.StartWork))
    t.Start()

    Return New ResponseItem(CheckGUID.ToString)

End Function
```